# Infinite product of an analytic function on the right half plane

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analyticity, infinite-product

I want to know whether $G_t=\prod_{i=1}^\infty G(s)^i$ is defined and analytic on the right half plane for an analytic $G(s)$ on the right half plane.

If so, is $L^{-1}\left(G_t\frac{1}{s}\right)$ bounded?

Comment: Typically, the product won't converge. Wherever $\lvert G(s)\rvert > 1$, the sequence of partial products isn't bounded, and wherever $\lvert G(s)\rvert < 1$, the product converges to $0$ (which means the product doesn't converge in $\mathbb{C}^\ast$). It converges iff $G \equiv 1$.